# phpmailer en hosting envio de correos

Tags: php, phpmailer

estoy utilizando la clase phpmailer para el envio de correos desde mi página web, cuando lo utilizo de manera local, el correo es enviado correctamente, pero cuando lo utilizo en el servidor solo me muestra que no ha sido posible aceptar la contraseña de mi usuario. Adjunto el codigo.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHPMailer - SMTP (Gmail) advanced test</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within     class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw    exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

try {
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug  information (for testing)
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "yourusername@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";            // GMAIL password
$mail->AddAddress('whoto@otherdomain.com', 'John Doe');
$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
$mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
$mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
$mail->MsgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'));
$mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer.gif');      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.gif'); // attachment
$mail->Send();
echo "Message Sent OK</p>\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

el error es el siguente

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Password not accepted from server: 534-5.7.14
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Creo que este enlace podría ayudarte. El problema parece similar, aunque tratado en inglés:
[PHPMailer - SMTP ERROR: Password command failed when send mail from my server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937586/phpmailer-smtp-error-password-command-failed-when-send-mail-from-my-server)

Resumiendo, el problema podría estar causado por algún tipo de aplicación externa que intenta usar tu cuenta de correo, el intento reiterado de iniciar la sesión o el inicio de sesión desde un país diferente.

Una posible solución para algunos usuarios consiste en:

-Acceder a la cuenta a través de la web

-Comprobar los intentos recientes de acceder a la cuenta y aceptar el acceso sospechoso: [link](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity?hl=en&pli=1)

-Desactivar la función de bloqueo de aplicaciones / tecnologías sospechosas: [link](https://www.google.com/settings/u/0/security/lesssecureapps)

Además de lo anterior, algunos usuarios han reportado tener que borrar el captcha para logearse.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza. Entiendo que la respuesta ha quedado subsanada adecuadamente a pesar de la valoración, que entiendo es anterior a la edición.

Comment: No puedo decir si ha sido subsanada. Solo puedo decir que ha sido editada y tiene mayor contenido a diferencia de solo el enlace. Será la comunidad con sus votos la que decidirá si es contenido de calidad o no.